# subquestion 2 : original Q "Difference between MSK and GMSK?"

Tags: digital-communications, qpsk, linear-phase, gmsk, oqpsk

if we talk about a modulation, we mention a linear and nonlinear modulation.
GMSK is nonlinear modulation, but it can be derived from a linear modulation as MSK, PAM and we talk about a linear approximation.

1. As I understood, the linear approximation, it is a representation a phase of a signal as a sum of two phases, right?  Write as the sum of PAM signals?
2. How does a block scheme of the linear approximation look? I have read some researches and in the most of them it was represented as a quadrature modulation structure. Does it mean I can represent GMSK as QPSK and Gaussian filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Laurent Decomposition** is the approximation for GMSK as a sum of PAM signals.

This technique is most useful for GMSK with partial response signaling, which is when we overlap subsequent pulses to send more date in less time which serves to increase the spectral efficiency at the expense of introducing intentional inter-symbol interference (ISI).

This does not simplify the transmitter, as compared to the very simple implementation I have detailed [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82003/subquestion-original-q-difference-between-msk-and-gmsk/82007#82007) with a Gaussian filter and NCO (which supports partial response signaling directly), but the Laurent decomposition shines in the receiver implementation for partial response GMSK. This is because the optimum receiver would need to correlate to every possible phase trajectory over the duration of symbol overlap, which creates a trellis of possibilities, with complexity increasing by the number of symbols that are overlapped. A Viterbi decoder is an efficient but still computationally intensive operation for implementing such an optimum receiver. The use of the Laurent Decomposition simplifies the Viterbi decoder by reducing the number of states in the trellis.

More details on Laurent Decomposition for GMSK can be found [here](https://www.atlantis-press.com/article/125913177.pdf). and the original paper by Pierre A. Laurent is:

"Exact and Approximate Construction of Digital Phase Modulations by Superposition of Amplitude Modulated Pulses (AMP)", IEEE Transactions on Communications, Vol. COM-34 No 2 February 1986. pp 150-160

Comment: you wrote, it can reduce the number of states in the trellis of the decoder. Could you provide more details?

Comment: i dont understand how laurent decomposition , modulator, can reduce the number of states

Comment: See this link and specifically on page 76, what he refers to as the "Laurent Expansion". The point is each successive term of the Laurent Decomposition has less and less energy, so even if you use just the first term (which is the linear result you are looking for, you get most of the energy (suboptimum but the optimum linear result). https://etd.lib.metu.edu.tr/upload/1057348/index.pdf

Comment: i have read about it, but how it helps to reduce number of states in the trellis? GMSK is only modulation technique at the transmitter side.

Comment: I am referring to demodulation of GMSK in a receiver. As I noted, I don't see any real advantage of using this in the transmitter compared to the (simple) implementation I gave with an NCO and Gaussian filter. We can implement the transmitter as I suggested, and then (and especially if we use partial response signaling) we can implement a suboptimum receiver using the Laurent Decomposition. Otherwise you would use the Viterbi algorithm as an efficient approach to correlate to every possible combination of overlapping symbols (in the receiver) which is the trellis I refer to.

Comment: If your modulation is GMSK you would use a GMSK modulator in the transmitter, and a GMSK demodulator in the receiver - just because we use a linear approximation in the receiver does not necessitate that the transmitter be changed to that same approximate waveform- the idea is we are minimizing the error in implementing the demodulation of a standard based waveform, not creating a different waveform entirely.

Comment: I thought we use a linear approximation at the transmitter side, in the modualator. is it used in the demodulator ?

Comment: You can certainly use it in the modulator. As I said, I don't see any real advantage (simplification) in doing that-- but that doesn't preclude doing that.  The real advantage is in the receiver where it can significantly decrease the resources required for implementation. (please avoid ongoing chat in the comments as the moderators discourage it as recommended by StackExchange; this will get flagged).

Comment: if i implement a llinear approxcimated gmsk modulator, does it mean i dont have Q signal ( imag))?

Comment: You do - there are two filters to implement the equivalent complex filter- if your modulator is done with a real digital IF output then you will see a sine and cosine multiplier. “I” is typically what is fed into the cosine product and “Q” is what is fed into the sine product. If you see that then whatever goes into the related pulse shaping fitters would be “I” and “Q”.

Comment: Will the ouput signals of GMSK based on Laurent decomposition and GMSK nonlinear ( filter, integrator) have the same phase?

Comment: Yes, sufficiently so, and exactly so if you used every term in the decomposition —- the idea of the Laurent decomposition is to create the same waveform. You would jot need a different receiver if you did the transmitter one way or the other.