# GMSK Transmitter Implementation based on AMP representation ( laurent decomposition)

Tags: digital-communications, gmsk

Implementation of a linear approximated GMSK block scheme based on Laurent decomposition.
My goal is the Implementation of the following [block scheme](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/monograph/series3/chapter2.pdf):

[image]
I think $v_k$ is an NRZ element ( 1 or -1).

```
ovs = 4;
L = 3 % laurent decomposition
Tr = 3;% truncation length
N = 20; 
a = randi([0,1],N,1);
vk = 2*a-1;
```

`vk` is an input for the first branch of this block scheme and the first S/P converter and for the second.
An input of the second S/P converter, `vk_3` looks like:

```
vk_1 =  kron(ones(length(vk), 1), 0);  
vk_1(1) = vk(end);
for i = 1: length(vk)-1
    vk_1(i+1) = vk(i);
end
vk_2 =  kron(ones(length(vk),1), 0);  
vk_2(1) = vk(end-1);
vk_2(2) = vk(end);
for i = 1: length(vk)-2
    vk_2(i+2) = vk(i);
end
vk_3 = vk .* vk_1 .* vk_2;
```

S/P converter separate the input signal into 2: the first signal contains odd elements, the second contains the even elements. Before I apply `C0` and `C1` I take a product with `(-1)^k` and upsample the signals:

```
Tsym = 2* ovs; % ovs – oversampling ratio
ai_1 = vk(1:2:end);
aq_1 = vk(2:2:end);

for i = 1:length(ai_1)
    ai_1(i) = ai_1(i) .* (-1)^(i); 
    aq_1(i) = aq_1(i) .* (-1)^(i); 
end

ai_1 = [ai_1 zeros(length(ai_1),Tsym-1)]; 
ai_1=ai_1.';                              
ai_1=ai_1(:);                             

aq_1 = [aq_1 zeros(length(aq_1),Tsym-1)];  
aq_1=aq_1.';                               
aq_1=aq_1(:);                              

ai_1 = [ai_1(:) ; zeros(Tsym/2,1)].';       
aq_1 = [zeros(Tsym/2,1); aq_1(:)].';
```

The same implementation has the signal ``vk_3`.

```
I_1= filter(C0,1,ai_1);
Q_1 = filter(C0,1,aq_1);
IQ_1 = I_1 – 1i*Q_1
```

IF I take BT = 0.5, the second branch with `C1` will not have a big influence of the result, so I skip its implementation.

I compute a phase of the `IQ_1` : `unwrap(atan2(Q_1,I_1))` and compare it with a phase of GMSK transmitter (I-Q representation)
[image]

The result of the comparison:

[image]

[Mr Dan Boschen](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82003/subquestion-original-q-difference-between-msk-and-gmsk#comment172144_82007) explained that both produce identical results (not an approximation).

In my simulation you see I have a big difference more than 1 rad. I have  mistaken in my simulation, but what the mistake is and how to find it I have no idea.

Did I implement GMSK Transmitter based on AMP  wrong ( the first block)?

Comment: I'll have to repeat that Dan didn't say the Laurent approximation was identical to the nonlinear method for generating GMSK, he said that the appropriate linear method was identical to the nonlinear method. May I ask why you choose to approximate the Gaussian using the Laurent decomposition? This feels really strange, as your system has no advantages from it. What's the motivation for that? Why choose such a bad approximation?

Comment: Note that I'd argue that without a technical reason to use this *very* truncated and suboptimal approximation, yes, your choice of filter approximation was wrong.

Comment: @MarcusMüller My big limitation, a reason is a transceiver with linear filtering. If I want to implement nonlinear method as Dan suggested, I need to implement it in an addition board (ZYNQ/FPGA). Oversampling ratio will decrease my data rate of the transceiver and resultant data rate is too small for my research. I have found with Laurent I can linearized method and it will perfect match. So... transiever and desired data rate are my reasons for this choice.

Comment: @MarcusMüller "Note that I'd argue that without a technical reason to use this very truncated and suboptimal approximation, yes, your choice of filter approximation was wrong. ".... do you mean the matlab function ` filter` or something else?

Comment: I mean the fact that you're using a length 3 Laurent decomposition instead of actually implementing the Gaussian, which is not any more computationally hard. I'm really not sure you know what you're doing there. *Why did you choose to do the Laurent decomposition? Why not simply use a reasonable-length Gaussian filter tap vector?* We've established in a previous question of yours that 3 is too short. And you're not only too short, you're on top approximating the filter badly. I really don't understand why.